# .ppt/.pptx parser or XML converter in PHP

Tags: php, xml, converters, powerpoint

I'm trying to find a way to count words of .ppt/.pptx files but can't figure out how to do. I came through the function below but doesn't seem to be working:

```
function parsePPT($filename) {
    $fileHandle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($filename));
    $lines = explode(chr(0x0f),$line);
    $outtext = '';

    foreach($lines as $thisline) {
        if (strpos($thisline, chr(0x00).chr(0x00).chr(0x00)) == 1) {
            $text_line = substr($thisline, 4);
            $end_pos   = strpos($text_line, chr(0x00));
            $text_line = substr($text_line, 0, $end_pos);
            $text_line = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$text_line);
            if (strlen($text_line) > 1) {
                $outtext.= substr($text_line, 0, $end_pos)."\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return $outtext;
}
```

If not counting directly from ppt output text, it should be a way to convert it in XML or other format and then easily output the text?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:** The following function does the job for .PPTX files but .PPT:

```
function parsePPT($input_file){
    $zip_handle = new ZipArchive;
    $output_text = "";
    if(true === $zip_handle->open($input_file)){
        $slide_number = 1; //loop through slide files
        while(($xml_index = $zip_handle->locateName("ppt/slides/slide".$slide_number.".xml")) !== false){
            $xml_datas = $zip_handle->getFromIndex($xml_index);
            $xml_handle = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml_datas, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            $output_text .= strip_tags($xml_handle->saveXML());
            $slide_number++;
        }
        if($slide_number == 1){
            $output_text .="";
        }
        $zip_handle->close();
    }else{
    $output_text .="";
    }
    return $output_text;
}
```

Comment: Why you don't try a class like [this one](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation)?

Comment: @fusion3k Thanks for your answer! Seems like it only does the writing part "A pure PHP library for writing presentations files"...

Comment: Au contraire, it's quite capable of reading (ppt, pptx and odp files) as well as writing, like most of the projects in the PHPOffice suite

Comment: Read careful also the example section

Comment: However `"If not counting directly from pdf output text"`.... is your question about PowerPoint files or PDF files?

Comment: @MarkBaker About PPT files sorry, edited my question. I found a working function for pptx files but it's not working for ppt files.

Comment: `ppt` files use the `PowerPoint97` Reader